# Strange value set as a key in the array in cakephp2

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-2.0

I have the problem with the following code. The query sent was normal, just fetching all the data I need. However, When I print_r the $data, the all the datas from find('all')  are not contained in [MYDATA] but also set in an unknown ['c'] and ['a'] array. Has anyone encounter this kind of weird problem ? Some examples or hint would be great. I would love to hear from you!

```
 $data = $this->MYDATA->find(
            'all',
            array(
                'conditions' =>
                    array(
                        array('my_id' => $var['id']),

                    ),
                'order' =>array('my_name'=>'DESC')
        ));
```

The following is the result from $data when using the 'my_name'=>'DESC' condition.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [MYDATA] => Array
            (
                [id] => 79
                [my_birth_day] => 1990-06-20
                [my_address] => 400
                [my_age] => 26
                [my_name] => Joy
                [my_id] => 1
                [created] => 2017-06-19 15:39:44
            )

        [c] => Array
            (
                [my_test] => math
            )

        [a] => Array
            (
                [my_date] => 2017-08-13
            )

    )
```

Without using the'my_name'=>'DESC' condition. This is the correct array. I want it to have the values return like this.

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [mydata] => Array
            (
                [id] => 79
                [my_birth_day] => 1990-06-20
                [my_address] => 400
                [my_age] => 26
                [my_name] => Joy
                [my_id] => 1
                [my_test] => math
                [created] => 2017-06-19 15:39:44
                [my_date] => 2017-08-13
            )
```

Comment: Can you please share your model and controller name?

Comment: The Controller name is  MyDataManagerController and the model name is MyData.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get most of the benefits of Cakephp then must follow cakephp 2 conventions. As you mentioned in the comment that you model is **MyData** then it must be **MyData** not **MyData** while fetching data from the database. Please change **MYDATA** to **MyData**.

```
 $data = $this->MyData->find(
                               'all',
                                array(
                                     'conditions' =>array('my_id' => $var['id']),
                                     'order' =>array('my_name'=>'DESC')
                                      )
                           );
 pr($data);
```

You can learn more about cakephp 2 conventions from here:

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html